# What is the nth term of the series? $0, 0 , 1 , 3 , 6 , 10 ....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I am trying to find the relation between the number of nodes and the number of connections possible. So if there are $0$ nodes, that means $0$ connections possible, $1$ node still means $0$ connections possible, $2$ nodes $1$ connection possible, $3$ nodes $3$ connection and so on. How can I find the relation between $n$ nodes and the number of possible connections ?

Comment: https://oeis.org/search?q=0%2C+0+%2C+1+%2C+3+%2C+6+%2C+10&sort=&language=&go=Search

Comment: The raseon why there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ connections between $n$ nodes is that each node is connected to $(n-1)$ other nodes. So if you count how many "ends" exist they are $(n-1)n$ and every connection has two ends.

Comment: Four answers so far and I see no mention of triangular numbers...

Comment: See [OEIS A161680](https://oeis.org/A161680) for $\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$, or [OEIS A000217](https://oeis.org/A000217) for $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, or [Wikipedia: triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Answer (score 14):

the sequence is $a_0,a_1,a_2\dots$ with $a_n=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$

Comment: Great! Thanks. It helped!

Answer (score 8):

Let $a_n$ be the number of connections for $n$ nodes.

For $n > 0$, we have $a_n = a_{n-1} + n-1$ because among the $a_n$ connections, there are $n-1$ of them that connect to the $n^{th}$ node while $a_{n-1}$ of them didn't.

Rewrite above expression as $a_k - a_{k-1} = k-1$.
Start summing both sides from $k = 1$ to $n$, we get

$$a_n - a_0 = \sum_{k=1}^n (k-1) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k-1)-(k-1)(k-2)}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Together with $a_0 = 0$, we find $a_n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ for $n > 0$.
Since this is trivially true at $n = 0$, we have $a_n = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ in general.

Answer (score 6):

*Hint:* If you have graph on $n$ nodes, an edge in the graph corresponds to a choice of $2$ of these nodes (the $2$ which the edge connects). Hence the number of possible edges in the graph is the number of ways you can choose $2$ nodes. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yep. I can now :)

Comment: Great - glad I could help :)

Comment: Just stumbled across your hint again. You meant something like this, right?  `n! / ((n - 2)! * 2!)`

Answer (score 1):

$a_n - a_{n-1} = n-2 \implies a_n = n-2 + n-3 +....+1 =  ...$